# Creating a concurrent safe map, lock or goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

I created a map that is safe for concurrent access, in each of the operations (or compound operations) I wrapped the operation with a lock.

```
func .. {
  mu.Lock()
  defer mu.Unlock()
  ..
}
```

Could I use goroutines for this also?  Should I be using goroutines?

Comment: if all you need is a lock, what are you going to use goroutines for?

Comment: A lock is usually the best approach for synchronizing simple map access.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631561/should-goroutine-channel-based-mechanism-replace-a-concurrent-map, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063473/map-with-concurrent-access, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725098/creating-a-concurrent-safe-map-lock-or-goroutine, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192173/nice-go-idiomatic-way-of-using-a-shared-map, etc

Comment: To directly answer your question-- yes, that would work with goroutines. But you should really think about your design, and whether or not your design needs to include goroutines (since you asked if you *should* be using them), or if you can get away without using them.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer necessary in Go 1.9 and later. There is already a map implementation for concurrent use [`sync.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map).